# CSS Grid single column layout for mobile without media queries

Tags: css, css-grid

I have CSS Grid layout for desktop screens going in clockwise like this:

[image: Layout picture with 4 sections, going in clockwise order]

**Code:**

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1px 1px;
  grid-template-areas: "one two" "four three";
}

.one { grid-area: one; }

.two { grid-area: two; }

.three { grid-area: three; }

.four { grid-area: four; }
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
  <div class="four"></div>
</div>
```

For mobile & tablet screens I want these sections to get stacked in increasing order:

```
This: 1 | Not this: 1
      2 |           2
      3 |           4
      4 |           3
```

**Can this be done without using media queries?** I feel I'm missing something simple.

**Edit:** From the answers so far it seems we must use media queries for something like this. Accepting the first answer.

Comment: Why you don't want to use media queries? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: @SMAKSS No particular reason. I was using media queries only for this layout in my project, so I thought maybe there might be a way not to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you must use media query

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "one" "two" "three" "four";
}
```

Comment: They will be automatically stacked one on each other. You can define media query for desktop and than apply that layout with grid areas

Comment: I am already using media queries for this but I'm not good with grid, so I thought I may have overlooked some non-media query way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, AFAIK, in any case, if you want to change your layout for different screen size devices, you should use media queries *no matter what*, to indicate which layout should appear in each screen size domain.

So with this assumption, your code should be something like this:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px 1px;
  grid-template-areas: "one two" "four three";
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    /* If you intend to use 1fr for each column indicating grid-template-columns is not required */
    grid-template-areas: "one" "two" "three" "four";
  }
}

.one {
  grid-area: one;
}

.two {
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  grid-area: three;
}

.four {
  grid-area: four;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
  <div class="four">4</div>
</div>
```